# AngularJS: filter a dropdown directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/jemaineosia/jJRfw/6/)

how can i filter my dropdown directive using the custom attribute?

```
$scope.myKeyword = [
        {Id: 1, Keyword:"ActivityType", Description: "Active"}, 
        {Id: 2, Keyword:"ActivityType", Description: "InActive"}, 
        {Id: 3, Keyword:"ActivityType", Description: "Deleted"},
        {Id: 4, Keyword:"MarketSegment", Description: "Fashion"},
        {Id: 5, Keyword:"MarketSegment", Description: "IT"},
        {Id: 6, Keyword:"MarketSegment", Description: "F&B"},
        {Id: 7, Keyword:"MarketSegment", Description: "Manufacturing"},
    ];
```

directive tag

```
<keywords supplier-id="supplier.Id" keyword-type="MarketSegment"  title="Choose Status" label="" array="myKeyword" opt-value="Id" opt-description="Description"></keywords>
```

I want to filter the dropdown by MarketSegment provided.

Comment: I found the solution, just add filter:keywordType in the directive template. this is the [update link](http://jsfiddle.net/jemaineosia/jJRfw/7/)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, just add filter:keywordType in the directive template. this is the update [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jemaineosia/jJRfw/7/)

```
<select ng-model="supplierId" ng-options="a[optValue] as a[optDescription] for a in array | filter: keywordType" required>'
```